# Query stuck with PGA memory operation wait Oracle 12.2

Tags: query-optimization

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (LWNEIGHBORREL_GNBID,
                      '[^;]+',
                      1,
                      LEVEL)    AS GNBID
  FROM ericssonlw."NRCellCU"
 WHERE loaddate_ = TRUNC (SYSDATE)
```

CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
LENGTH (LWNEIGHBORREL_GNBID)
- LENGTH (REPLACE (LWNEIGHBORREL_GNBID, ';'))
+ 1;

The table NRCellCU is having current statistics and 680K rows.
The query runs for hours and the only wait event I see is "PGA memory operation".
Ask Tom merely says that tune the query.
loaddate_ column is indexed.
Sample output expected:

GNBID

5605434
5605106
5605301
5605434
...

explain plan:

Plan hash value: 3522999867

---

### | Id  | Operation                     | Name     | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| Pstart| Pstop |

### |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |          |    680K|    74M| 14855   (1)|       |       |
|*  1 |  FILTER                       |          |        |       |            |       |       |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|          |        |       |            |       |       |
|   3 |    PARTITION RANGE ALL        |          |    680K|    74M| 14855   (1)|     1 |1048575|
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | NRCellCU |    680K|    74M| 14855   (1)|     1 |1048575|

How do I go about tuning this simple query?
Any help will be appreciated!

Tried to use WITH clause but is really not necessary. Query does not improve.